# points not accessible after QVector insert function

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor, qvector, rule-of-three

I am trying to follow the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), however doing this has cause a problem specifically with QVector's insert function.

after adding a copy constructor and destructor, My program will produce an error where a vector of points are no longer accessible, and so the copy constructor fails to re-assign the points.

Here are some snippets from my code

```
QVector<QPointF> *mList = nullptr;
int area;

Shape::Shape()
{
    mList = new QVector<QPointF>();
    area = 0;
}
Shape::Shape(const Shape &obj)
{
    mList = new QVector<QPointF>();
    mList = *obj.mList;
    area = obj.area;
}
Shape::~Shape()
{
    delete mList;
}
```

Now I sort a group of 'Shape' objects by their area using qSort, which uses the QVector functions.

```
void T::sortByArea()
{     
    qSort(listOfShapes);
}
```

When this method finishes. I find that one of the shapes now has an mList that has the value `<not accessible>`. Which only occurs in the sort when QVector::insert(int i, const T &value) is used.

---

Up until this point, this list of shapes is edited and manipulated but this is the only time up to this point that a Shape's list becomes inaccessible. What is the reasoning and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, since you use `const` in your copy constructor argument list, the QVector is only shallow copied and not deep copied. This is because QVector is an [implicitly shared container](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html).

Removing the `const` should work, but better solution may be to explicitely copy the entire vector (eg. using `memcopy`), not just using the QVector's `=` operator.